How to monitor NFS activity on Windows 11?
I have a home NAS running unRaid and my Windows 11 machine mounts it through NFS as a mapped device. From the network usage in task manager I see my Windows 11 machine is constantly reading the NFS to its full bandwidth.
I tried looking into resource monitor. Its disk page shows only my local disks. And the network page doesn't show any program with this amount of reading. When I reboot, such weird reading would be gone for a while and then show later.
Is there anyway to know which process is accessing which files on my NFS just like what is shown in the resource monitor for my local disks?
